# creating a UDP connection with iOS and an embeddeddevice

Tags: ios, embedded, udp

If I have an iOS client and an embedded device that I want to communicate between the two with a WiFi connection using UDP, do I need to write a server (python or something) to facilitate the connection? I am trying to look online but there are a lot of ambigious articles.

Thanks

Comment: Where you might want the assistance of a third device in the server role is to help with identifying the the phone and embedded device to each other, though there are other options.  Also likely you have a wireless access point (or the embedded device is acting as one) rather than a direct connection between the two, though adhoc wireless (and some newer peer-to-peer schemes) starts to become possible with more recent devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write a server application for the device (iOS or embedded) that will be listening for data.

However, for a simple, single-client UDP connection, your server is basically just a UDP socket, which you bind to the port you want to use - and then start listening for data on. You don't need any connection-handling as UDP is connectionless.

On your client, you just send data to the IP and port of your server, and that's it.

I've done this myself, connecting my iPod Touch to a small ITX computer (running WinXP), to [control a small mobile robot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OrJTeyz_5U) over WiFi.